# How to add repeat event in ui-calendar

Tags: angularjs, ui-calendar

I am using http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/ in my application.

I want to add birthday event that repeat each year.

for example

student 1 birthday is `12-jan-2006.`

```
$scope.birthdayEvent = [
        {title:'ABC',start:'2006-1-12',allDay: true,stick:true}]
```

This is show event in 2006 calendar.

I want this event to be shown all years the 12th January.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

When the app is open it just checks the current year and evaluates the current year in the `birthDay` expression. So, when the app opens every time or executes, It will get the current year from the Date and sets the year:

```
$scope.birthDay = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 12);

$scope.birthdayEvent = [
        {title: 'ABC', start: $scope.birthDay, allDay: true, stick: true}
]
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to add an explanation to your post that talks about how the code works. This allows new developers to understand what the code does.

Comment: Sure, I will add some explanation

Comment: @charan " new Date(new Date().getFullYear, 0, 12) " this line gives me the invalid date error . have you tried it ?